# Proving that a function has a constant value ($0$)

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

The question is:

> Prove that $\forall x>0 \ \arctan (x) + \arctan (1/x) = \pi/2$

I did the following: I put $f(x)=\arctan (x) + \arctan (1/x) - \pi/2$, so I need to prove that $\forall x>0 \ f(x)= 0$.

Comment: Take $\tan$ of both sides or move one $\arctan$ to the right, subtract $\pi/4$ from both sides and then take the $\tan$ of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use the fact that:

$$
\tan \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2}-x \right)=\dfrac{1}{\tan x}
$$

and $\tan\left(\arctan x \right)=x$

Answer (score 0):

Personally I know 2 methods but the most easy and straightforward one is to calculate the derivative. You should show that it is equal to $0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$. But this will only show that the function's constant but I guess you can easly compute its value.

Answer (score 0):

first note that $$\cot^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$$ since let $$\cot^{-1}x=\theta$$ implies $$x=\cos\theta$$ imply $$\frac{1}{x}=\tan\theta$$now it is enough to show $$tan^{-1}x+cot^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$now since $$x=\cot\theta=tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$implies $$\tan^{-1}x+\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ now substitute $$\theta$$ .